# lxml - parse an xml with no line breaks in it

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml iterparse in python to loop through the elements in my xml file. It works fine with most of the xmls, but fails for some. One of them has no line breaks in it. The error and a sample of such xml are as below. Any clues?

Thanks!!

```
<root><person><name>"xyz"</name><age>"10"</age></person><person><name>"abc"</name><age>"20"</age></person></root>
```

error -

```
XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 1, column 1
```

code -

```
from lxml import etree  

def parseXml(context,elemList):         
    for event, element in context:        
        if element.tag in elemList:                   
            #read text and attributes is any
        element.clear()  

def main(object):  
    elemList= ['name','age','id']     
    context=etree.iterparse(fullFilePath, events=("start","end"))      
    parseXml(context,elemList)
```

Comment: I have added the code sample.

Answer (score 2):

etree.iterparse expects buffer for source argument. And name of variable you passing, "fullFilePath", tells me that it's not file (So parser is trying to parse file_path insted of file content  ).
Try passing opened file instead.

```
context=etree.iterparse(open(fullFilePath), events=("start","end"))
```

or string:

```
from lxml import etree

xml = '<root><person><name>"xyz"</name><age>"10"</age></person><person><name>"abc"</name><age>"20"</age></person></root>\n'

def parseXml(context,elemList):
    for event, element in context:
        if element.tag in elemList:
            print element.tag,
        element.clear()

def main():
    elemList= ['name','age','id']
    context=etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml), events=("start","end"))
    parseXml(context,elemList)

main()

>>>name name age age name name age age
```

PS: And what to do you mean by this?

> def main(object):

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Pill. Actually both fullFilePath and open(fullFilePath) work. Unfortunately, the xml file itself had error. And since I had a set of files, I opened and checked the format of the file which was correct (though error was on the next file) and thought my parser was wrong.